# Why does an opportunity is not shown for the converted lead?

Tags: reporting, opportunity, leads, lead-conversion

I have an interesting issue where an opportunity that was closed of a converted lead, does not show on the relevant report.

1. A lead was created
2. The lead was converted to an Account + Contact
3. The account has only 1 contact
4. 2 opportunities were created - 1 was closed won, 2nd is still in process.
5. Under the contact's page - we only see the 2nd oppty
6. In the relevant report - I do not see the closed won oppty (I should [and I see] other opptys closed from converted leads)

I guess it has to do something with relating the oppty with the contact, but I don't understand why it's not happening by default?

Where do I fix this?

This breaks the money-flow and our marketing efforts.

EDIT: As per Techtrekker

I do see that the contact is registered as a contact role on one oppty (the open one), and not on the second oppty.

[image]

Adding the Contact to a contact role on the missing oppty: still did not add that data to the report (report of income from converted leads)

!!!!
Does this have an effect that we do NOT create an oppty on the lead conversion process? - We only create the oppty's AFTER the conversion is complete.

And if this is the case - how to solve it?

However, the role part is empty, and he is not marked as primary. In our org, we do not (never used) the contact role, isn't it by default that if a single user exists for a company, he becomes the primary ?

Comment: Is the Contact a Opp Contact Role on both Opportunities ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leads have hidden fields to represent the Account/Contact/Opportunity records they were converted into.  Your Lead report is most likely using these fields only.  Because of this, other Opportunities added would not show up.  You most likely need to create a new Opportunity report.

Comment: I use the correct report - asking for opptys made by converted leads. Apparently, the work flow on this case was wrong, as a new account was created, and the lead was than converted into **an existing** account.

Answer (score 1):

Your report is a Contacts with Opportunities report, It will only show you opportunities that are related to contacts.

From your description I assume that having opportunities related to contacts is important for your bussiness model.

Opportunities are commonly created in 3 ways:

1. From lead conversion, where you are also creating an Account and Contact.
2. From the **Account** page - > Pressing "New Opportunity"
3. From the **Contact** page - > Pressing "New Opportunity"

Using method 1 & 3 will relate the opportunity to the contact, using method 2 will not.

The standard approach is to simply remove the "New Opportunity" button from the Account page (Opportunity related list). And to train users to always create opportunities from the Contact page.

Comment: Great tip, I'll ask sales and marcom if they want it this way.